# Is there fast approximation of the n-th power of diagonalizable matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, diagonalization, svd

My thoughts on the subject.

Because of diagonalizability $A$ can be  written as 
$A = PDP^{-1}$ and then 
$A^n = PD^nP^{-1}$ here $P$ is matrix of eigenvectors and $D$ is diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A$.

This can be truncated 
$A^n \approx P_kD^n_k[P^{-1}]_k$ where we a taking only first k columns/rows of matrices correspondingly. But I need find $P^{-1}$ first and this is computationally intensive task.

Comment: Isn't P orthonormal?

Comment: @giorgi It's not, unless $A$ is normal.

Comment: @giorgi: 3.5 years too late, but the proper term for a matrix with orthonormal columns is actually "orthogonal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just computationally intensive. It's also numerically unstable. Observe this:

$$A = P D P^{-1}, \quad P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 + \varepsilon \end{bmatrix}, \quad D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ & \varepsilon \end{bmatrix}.$$

For $\epsilon = 10^{-13}$, for example, Mathematica code

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-9;
P = {{1, 1}, {1, 1 + \[Epsilon]}} // N;
mD = N[DiagonalMatrix[{0, \[Epsilon]}], 100] // N;
Print["A = ", (A = P.mD.Inverse[P]) // MatrixForm]
Print["A^17 = ", (P1 = MatrixPower[A, 17]) // MatrixForm]
Print["P D^17 P^-1 = ", (P2 = P.MatrixPower[mD, 17].Inverse[P]) //   MatrixForm]
Print["A^17 - P D^17 P^-1 = ", P1 - P2 // MatrixForm]
```

will output

```
A = (
-1. 1.
-1. 1.
)

A^17 = (
0.  0.
0.  0.
)

P D^17 P^-1 = (
-1.*10^-144 1.*10^-144
-1.*10^-144 1.*10^-144
)

A^17 - P D^17 P^-1 = (
1.*10^-144  -1.*10^-144
1.*10^-144  -1.*10^-144
)
```

This is, of course, a fabricated example. However, with larger matrices, errors will, of course, occur much easier.

Also, unless you know your eigenvalues to be real, the above approach (via Jordan decomposition) would involve complex arithmetic.

Unless you know $A$ to have some nice properties (i.e., very distinct eigenvalues), it's better to use the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition). If $A$ is real, this can be done with real arithmetic (with the small price of replacing triangular with quasitriangular factor) and there are quite nice ways to compute it. For example, the [QR algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm).

The drawback: you still need to implement the matrix power of a (quasi)triangular matrix.

Comment: The matrix in question has real eigenvalues, but the distinctiveness of eigenvalues cannot be guaranteed. I don't know modern literature well so the question: are there low rank approximations or probabilistic approximations available?  Anything will do, actually.

Comment: Also it is know that $A$ is stochastic.

Comment: Since the eigenvalues are real, are your matrices symmetric? Stohastic matrices are not really my area. You might find [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0025556478900056) and its references useful. Also, for a more general approach (i.e., disregarding stohasticity), [this paper](http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/index.php/The_nth_Power_of_a_Matrix_and_Approximations_for_Large_n) might come in handy.

Comment: Thank you for the references. A is in form of $A=\Lambda C$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $C$ is symmetric, both matrices are real.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to use that fact.

Comment: Thank you for you attention. The papers you have linked provided quite a few thought of my own.

Comment: One more question. Do I understand correctly that $P$ is matrix of right eigenvectors and $P^{-1}$  is matrix of left eigenvectors and I can solve partial eigenvalue problem for $A^T$ to find $P^{-1}$? So no need to inverse $P$?

Comment: From $A = P D P^{-1}$ you get $AP = PD$ or $P^{-1}A = DP^{-1}$, so the answer to your question is "yes". This is still numerically unstable. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Numerical_analysis) for an example better than mine. The example there can be seen as $A = \Lambda C$ for $\Lambda = \mathop{\rm diag}(1, \epsilon)$ and $C = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & \epsilon^{-1} \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Well, for some reason partial Schur decomposition subroutines are not available in libraries for the languages I'm working with: python and MATLAB. Is there some alternative to partial Schur decomposition? I'm actually quite surprised by absence of it, guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Matlab has [`schur`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/schur.html) and Python has [`linalg.schur`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html#schur-decomposition). Unlike SVD, Schur decomposition is a similarity relation, so I don't think there is such a thing as a "partial Schur decomposition" (similarity matrix has to be square, so I don't see how it could be reduced, while maintaining the dimension of the original matrix). However, the QR method (used for computing the Schur decomposition) should be quite fast, so you probably don't need a "reduced" method.

Comment: I really need reduced method due to size of the problem. Can I use Arnoldy process $AV_{k+1} = V_kH_k$ started from some vector $v_0$ to obtain sufficiently good approximation of $A$: $A \approx V_mH_mV_m^T$ or something similar?

Comment: I don't see how, unless **maybe** if you're actually looking for $A^nv$ and not $A^n$. If this is the case, I suggest opening a new question, as I'm not nearly familiar enough with Arnoldi to actually answer this. Also, [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) might be more suitable for such a question.